# Metaprogramming in Julia -- Splice integer into variable name

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

**Short Question:**

I have a Integer variable `N` and would like to write a macro to produce a single dummy variable `i_($N)`.

**An attempt:**

```
@generated function testfunc(N)
     :(i_($N))
end
testfunc(5) # Desired behavior i_5

ERROR: UndefVarError: i_ not defined
 in testfunc at none:2
```

**Longer explanation:**

I recently discovered [`Base.Cartesian`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/devdocs/cartesian/) in Julia. It has some handy tricks for generating dummy variables for indexing multidimensional arrays.

The `@ntuple` macro in Cartesian can produce sequences starting at 1. For example, `@ntuple 5 k->i_k` produces `(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4,i_5)`. Inside an @generated function, if `W=5` then `@ntuple ($W) k->i_k` will produce the same sequence. This doesn't work: `@ntuple 1 k->i_(k+$W)`

I can't figure out a way to just produce, e.g. `i_3` if `N=3` (this could be inside an @generated function).

My end goal is to use `@nloops` in Cartesian to loop over a sequence of dummy variables and store the results in some storage vector indexed by one of the dummy variables, e.g. something like:

```
@nloops ($W) i A begin
    # Example generated code for N=2, W=3:
    #    storage[i_2] *= A[i_1, i_2, i_3]
    storage[i_($N)] *= A[(@ntuple ($W) k->i_k)...]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a Integer variable N and would like to write a macro to produce a single dummy variable i_($N).

To answer your question directly, you can do this by:-

```
i_5 = 7

macro testfunc(expr)
    return symbol(:i_, expr)
end

@testfunc 5    #This give us back the value of `i_5`, which is 7
@testfunc(5)   #Another way to write the same macro.
```

So if we have a function:-

```
function foo()
    i_3 = 9
    return @testfunc(3)
end
```

`foo()` will give us the correct answer of `9`.

That said, it may still not be sufficient for what you want, which is to put the macro to use inside a function. In gist, when `@testfunc(N)` where `N = 3` generates `i_3`, we want to refer to `i_3` in the function, but if we write:-

```
function foo(N)
    i_3 = 9
    return @testfunc(N)
end
```

`foo(3)` will give us an `UndefVarError: i_N not defined`. Not sure whether there is any way to rectify it. There are 2 possibilities I can think of to workaround this, one is to write your process as a script in the global scope, another, is to put the whole function in quote.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't understand what exactly you want, but there are some notes:

1. `@generated` arguments are *Types* in the macro body. eg. in `@generated function testfunc(N)`, `N` is something like `Int64` rather than `3`.
2. if you want to concat a variable name, you may need to construct it by `Symbol` or something else, but not just quote.

eg.

```
macro testfunc(N)
    Symbol("i_$N")
end

@testfunc(2) # equivalent to i_2
```

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers suggest, the key is to explicitly construct the symbol you want and splice it into the generated expression.  Also note that you can simplify your `A[i_1, i_2, …]` expression with [`@nref`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/devdocs/cartesian/#macro-reference).

```
@nloops ($W) i A begin
    storage[$(symbol(:i_, N)] *= @nref $W A i
end
```

In my experience, the best way to learn how to use these macros is through the use of `macroexpand`:

```
julia> using Base.Cartesian
       W = 3
       N = 2
       macroexpand(:(@nloops ($W) i A begin
                         storage[$(symbol(:i_, N))] *= @nref $W A i
                     end))
quote  # cartesian.jl, line 31:
    for i_3 = 1:size(A,3) # cartesian.jl, line 32:
        nothing # cartesian.jl, line 33:
        begin  # cartesian.jl, line 31:
            for i_2 = 1:size(A,2) # cartesian.jl, line 32:
                nothing # cartesian.jl, line 33:
                begin  # cartesian.jl, line 31:
                    for i_1 = 1:size(A,1) # cartesian.jl, line 32:
                        nothing # cartesian.jl, line 33:
                        begin  # none, line 5:
                            storage[i_2] *= A[i_1,i_2,i_3]
                        end # cartesian.jl, line 34:
                        nothing
                    end
                end # cartesian.jl, line 34:
                nothing
            end
        end # cartesian.jl, line 34:
        nothing
    end
end
```